# more than 1 actions occuring at once onclick

Tags: jquery

i am using a click-open accordian-type script. the problem is that the selectors on which it is applied are repeated, and due to this on clicking a link, one only the child element of the clicked element should be affected, whereas all other list items (which are repeated) arebeing affected at the same time.

the jquery is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#odd-accordion ul.nextslide > li a").click(function(){
    $("ul.nextslide-second a").slideToggle('300');

    });
});
```

the html is like this:

```
<div class="adminmenuback">
    <div class="commonlogo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Wish2book">
    </div>
    <div class="searchh">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search"><span class="menutitle_rightimage"></span> 
    </div>

    <h2 class="menutitle"><span class="dashboard-icon"></span>Dashboard</h2>

    <ul class="adminmenu" id="odd-accordion">
        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">Flights</a></h3>
            <ul class="nextslide">
                <li><a href="#">abc</a>
                    <ul class="nextslide-second">
                        <li><a href="#">abc-child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">Flights</a></h3>
            <ul class="nextslide">
                <li><a href="#">abc</a>
                    <ul class="nextslide-second">
                        <li><a href="#">abc-child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">Flights</a></h3>
            <ul class="nextslide">
                <li><a href="#">abc</a>
                    <ul class="nextslide-second">
                        <li><a href="#">abc-child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

pls help. the jsfiddle link is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BVz97/

in the jsfiddle, just click "abc" and all abc-child will be selected

Comment: Your fiddle is incomplete.

Comment: Your fiddle appears to have js code but no html.  It won't work that way.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, how do you know? Did try?

Comment: @gdoron Yes.  It's blank.  The js doesn't generate anything, it just attaches to elements which don't exist.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, Sorry,I meant: `<sarcasm>` how do you know? Did try? `</sarcasm>` `:)`

Comment: @gdoron I was really hoping that was the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` to only find the one contained in the clicked element.

```
$("#odd-accordion ul.nextslide > li a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".nextslide").find("ul.nextslide-second a").slideToggle('300');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BVz97/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop propagation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#odd-accordion ul.nextslide > li a").click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
        $("ul.nextslide-second a").slideToggle('300');
    });
});
```